# g:plusone cb=gapi.loaded_0:96 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-plus

We're having a strange issue in only Chrome.

When using

```
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer async src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
    { lang: 'en-GB' }
</script>
```

The server is a normal cPanel on a dedicated box so not running from `file://` or anything.

But when we run it in chrome we get

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://apis.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://xxxxxxxx.co.uk').
```

And the button doesn't appear - we just get the console error message.

Comment: Is something not working or are you just getting this log message?

Comment: @abraham ha sorry forgot to add that detail - no the button doesnt render at all.